# F3 caching issue

Tags: caching, fat-free-framework

Recently, I got error

> Warning: require_once(account_header.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   /home/contestium/dev/temp/dev.contestium.com.tpl.0oyr4na on line 1
>   Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'account_header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in /home/contestium/dev/temp/dev.contestium.com.tpl.0oyr4na on line 1

I have disabled caching with

```
F3::set('CACHE',FALSE);
```

But it was not helpful for me. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When using cached files, your relative path won't work, as the cached files are not in the original file's directory.

You'll either need to provide the full path to 'account_header.php', or add the path to the directory containing such to your include path. This can either be done in your php.ini file, or at [runtime][1].

It looks like the cached files are still being used, right? If you delete those files, will it fetch the original file (and not the cached files)?